# Function of class $C^1$ $y(x)$ fulfills the condition $y'(x)=\cos{y(x)}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)$ exists.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Function of class $C^1$ $y(x)$ fulfills the condition $y'(x)=\cos{y(x)}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)$ exists.

---

We can see that for every $k$ function $y(x) \equiv k\pi+\frac{\pi}2$ fulfills equation $y'=cos{y}$

So when we start from the point from the intervals $(-\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi)$ for every k we have that our $y'$ is positive.

So if the solution for example starting from $1$ would stay in $(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2)$ then we have that $y(x)$ is increasing and limited so there's a limit in $+\infty$.

My problem is how to prove that every solution starting from $(-\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi)$ or $(\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi,\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi)$ will stay there.

I should use Picard–Lindelöf theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $y \mapsto \cos y$ is $\mathcal C^1$, you can indeed apply Picard-Lindelöf theorem. This implies that the solution to the IVP $y^\prime(x)= \cos y(x)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$ is locally unique.

Now consider a solution $y(x)$ of the IVP with $y_0 \notin \pi \mathbb Z+\pi/2$. If that solution would be defined for $x \in \mathbb R$ with $y(x) \in \pi \mathbb Z+\pi/2$, then, as $y^\prime(x)=0$, the solution should be the constant map equal to $y(x)$ according to uniqueness of Picard-Lindelöf theorem. A contradiction.

A complete solution to the initial question also requires to prove that a maximal solution to the IVP is defined on all $\mathbb R $. This is a consequence of what we just proved as if a solution would only exist in a bounded interval, it would blow up in a finite time.